# How to deal with a global fixed scale_fill_gradient2 for multiple plot in loop

Tags: r, for-loop, ggplot2, gridextra

I have a data.frame (CAMANOC) of species and Latitude/Longitude.

I applied a function and a for-loop to krige my data and use`grid.arrange` to plot all plot in one window.

Unfortunately, when I use `scale_fill_gradient2` the color gradient appears to have min limit and max limit from all my values. When `scale_fill_gradient2` is masked, everythings work.

Here is my code:

```
    CAMANOCKrigeage <- function(CAMANOC,CAMANOC.grid2){
  plotCAMANOC <- list() #Defining a list to save my maps
  for (j in 1:8) #Calling species
  {

      var.exp <- variogram((CAMANOC[[j]])~1, CAMANOC)
      var.mod=vgm(psill = 1, model = c("Exp", "Mat", "Sph"), nugget = 100, range = 2000,alpha = c(0, 45, 90, 135))
      var.fit=fit.variogram(var.exp,var.mod)

      krigeage = krige(formula = (CAMANOC[[j]])~1,CAMANOC,CAMANOC.grid2,model = var.fit)


      krig.output=as.data.frame(krigeage)

      names(krig.output)[1:4]<-c("long","lat","var1.pred","var1.var")
      layer1 <- c(geom_tile(data=krig.output,aes(fill=var1.pred)))


      plotCAMANOC[[j]] <- ggplot(data = krig.output,aes(x = long, y = lat)) +
          geom_polygon(data = oceanfort, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "white") +
          geom_polygon(data = coastlinefort, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), fill = "grey") +
          geom_path(data = landfort, aes(x = long, y = lat, group=group)) +
          ggtitle(names(CAMANOC)[j]) +
          coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-6,1),ylim = c(48,51)) +
          scale_fill_gradient2(name=bquote(atop("", ~cell.cm^-3)), 
                        high="green", mid="blue", low="red", 
                        space="Lab", midpoint = median(krig.output$var1.pred)) +
          labs(x = "Longitude") +
          labs(y = "Latitude") +
          theme_bw() +
          layer1


  }
  return(plotCAMANOC)
}


plotCAMANOC <- CAMANOCKrigeage(CAMANOC,CAMANOC.grid2)

do.call(grid.arrange,plotCAMANOC)
```

For a better view, two maps I have: 
[image]

I am sorry for the lack of reproductible example, I am not familiar with that.

Comment: Within your loop, try converting each ggplot to a grob object using `ggplotGrob()` before saving the result to plotCAMANOC[[j]]. The grob object will "remember" the gradient scale based on the min/max within that particular loop. If that isn't what you're looking for, please be more explicit about what you got versus what you had hoped to get. It's hard to troubleshoot in the dark.

Comment: @Z.Lin. Thank you for this objet. It works very well and give me the result I want